# Shutdown does not turn off computer

Tags: 18.04, grub2, shutdown

After a recent update (Ubuntu 18.04.4) on an Udoo Bolt, I have a problem when I shut down the computer.  It seems all running processes are killed, but the computer doesn't completely shut down (fan still runs, power light still on, etc). Updates to `GRUB` have not helped. I tried adding `apm=power_off`, `acpi=force` and `reboot=bios` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line without any success. I have also tried `sudo poweroff` from the terminal and that doesn't work either.

Any other ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you waited 60 minutes? I've had a problem where `shutdown` took 35+ minutes. Look at `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e` to see shutdown  logs

Comment: I have the same problem with Zorin OS on my Matebook D!
I asked on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/zorinos/comments/gny4l5/zorin_os_not_shutting_down_on_matebook_d_14/

Comment: same problem on Asus (Ubuntu 20.04LTS). My laptop doesn't shut down completely as you describe. I have searched and found this question cropping up a lot. has anybody filed a bug about this because it's clearly a problem?